# hot to install values.h header (c/c++) on cygwin

Tags: c++, c, cygwin

I want to install `values.h` on `cygwin`. I am running Windows OS.
I am compiling a code in C ,I need `values.h` and I am getting  this error

`fatal error: values.h: No such file or directory`

So how can I install `values.h` on `cygwin`

Comment: I believe that if you installed gcc correctly it should already be installed. Try `find /usr -type f -name values.h`.

Comment: It did find it in couple of locations

/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/values.h

/usr/include/libguile/values.h

I am using netbeans and still does not find this header

Answer (score 1):

You don't "install" header files. You just need to tell the compiler where they are. Usually that's the `-I` or `/I` option.

Comment: and how do I do that? I am newbie.

Comment: Of course you install header files; otherwise they would be missing from your system and you could not use `-I` to tell the compiler where they are...

Answer (score 1):

values.h is an old UNIX standard file it was
documented in issues 1 and 2 of the X/Open Portability Guide.
float.h was standardized in ANSI C in 1989 and had become widely
used before then. values.h was withdrawn from the standard in
issue 3 of the XPG in 1989, and never made it into POSIX at all.

In short, values.h has been obsolete for many years - any code
which wants to be portable should be changed to use the float.h
identifiers instead. If anyone wanted to do it, I can't imagine
any harm in adding a values.h to the cygwin distribution which #defines the values.h identifiers to their float.h equivalents,
but it would be better if the software which uses values.h were
changed to not do so.

Source : https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-01/msg00132.html